# How to get all dates clubbed in the main task in dhtmlxgantt?

Tags: jquery, dhtmlx, gantt-chart

My Scheduling Calendar contains task as "SIT" which has sub tasks i.e different applications. Look at [My Gantt Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnFZd.png).
Different applications are scheduled by dates, but the main task (in blue) is drawn only by the latest updated application schedule. I want to club my main task (SIT) from 1st April to 13th April as we have all applications scheduled within these dates.

Comment: try to add codes you tried to achieve the same and failed, from that point raise your question in a precise way to make everyone to analyze your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set type="project" for the blue task "SIT" with subtasks: https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__task_types.html#projecttasks

Tasks with type="project" depend on children tasks, i.e. project task starts, when its earliest child task starts, and ends, when its latest child ends.